# Programmatically Azure Policy Assignment with Exclusions

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-policy

I couldn't find any programmatic way to add exclusions to Azure policy assignment. Is it possible to create Azure policy assignment with exclusions or add exclusions to existing assignment using PowerShell, Azure CLI or Rest Api etc ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell to configure exclusion, but you should also look into using exemption ([Azure Policy exemption structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/exemption-structure)). The method name says New, but it also works for existing assignments. We store exclusions and exemptions in json structured files.

- [New-AzPolicyAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azpolicyassignment?view=azps-8.2.0) - use -NotScope to set exclusions
- [New-AzPolicyExemption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azpolicyexemption?view=azps-8.2.0) - use to set exemptions
- [Remove-AzPolicyExemption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/remove-azpolicyexemption?view=azps-8.2.0) - use to remove exemptions

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I will try and answer this as best I can, but this is worded a bit vaguely.

If you are referring to the Roles you can assign via RBAC at the resource group/resource level then there are predefined Roles that can be assigned via ARM Template deployments, PowerShell, Azure CLI etc.

There are also custom roles you can create via Azure CLI, Powershell, REST API, and ARM Template Deployments. These custom roles can include any of the permissions you so choose.

These roles can be used to give permissions or deny permissions to a subscription, resource group, or resource.

**Refer to these Microsoft document links for creating custom roles programmatically, paying special attention to the "NotAction" and "NotDataAction" properties since your question is regarding exclusions**

[Powershell Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/tutorial-custom-role-powershell)

[Azure CLI Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/tutorial-custom-role-cli)

[REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-rest)

[ARM Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-template)

**Refer to these Microsoft document links for adding/removing roles programmatically:**

[Powershell assign/remove roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-powershell)

[Azure CLI assign/remove roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-cli)

[Azure REST API add/remove roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-rest)

[ARM Template Deployment add/remove roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-template) **Cannot remove Role Assignment via ARM Template currently

By using both of these together you should be able to create custom roles, and assign those roles to Principals/Users to allow for customized permissions.

Comment: Thanks @Trent for the response. Its not about RBAC roles. Actually I am referring Azure Policy here. We can create a Azure policy and then can create an Assignment for the policy. You can refer MS Doc here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/assign-policy-portal. Adding Exclusions to an policy Assignment is optional and can be easily done via portal. I am looking for a programmatic way to do the same.

Comment: Sorry about that, unfortunately that's out of my area of expertise. Good luck!

Comment: I believe it can be achieved using providing list of resource ids for -NotScope parameter while creating assignment using azure powershell commandlet New-AzPolicyAssignment. I just created an assignment using it and seems promising; will update solution here after testing it. I should have tried it before :(                                        Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azpolicyassignment?view=azps-5.3.0